# "Automation error The server threw an exception. " when printing excel sheet in VB6

Tags: excel, printing, vb6

I have a function in VB6 which creates an excel sheet, saves it then I need to print it.
Everything goes fine, but when I try to print, I get "Automation error
The server threw an exception. "
Here is the code snippet:

```
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

sSavedFile = App.Path & "\Buff1" & ".xls"
xlSheet.SaveAs sSavedFile
xlSheet.PrintOut
```

The last row is giving me this error message.I use this code in another project, in VB9, and it's working like a charm.

Can someone help me with this? Maybe suggest another way to do this? I can print the whole workbook or just this sheet, it doesn't matter, I only have 1 sheet in the workbook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `xlSheet.PrintOut` should work but try `xlSheet.Sheets(1).Printout`

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the declaration, so in my case, xlsheet is the sheet, so it's  xlBook.Sheets(1).PrintOut.
Thank you sir.

Comment: since you ahd `xlSheet.SaveAs sSavedFile`, I assumed that you had defined your workbook as `xlSheet` :p else I would  have suggested that earlier :)

Comment: Just to make things clear if someone gets the same error, I edited the source.
Thanks again.

Comment: the shoudln't `xlSheet.SaveAs sSavedFile` be `xlBook.SaveAs sSavedFile`??

Comment: I'm just fixing a code in my workplace and it's working like that :)